# MS Word DDE: What does destroy my encoding?

Tags: .net, vba, encoding, ms-word, dde

I'm facing a problem with a MS Word DDE Automation controlled by our CRM system.

**The setup**

Base for the document created is a Word .dot template which fires a macro on Document.New. Inside this macro I create a .Net component registered for COM.

```
Set myCOMObject = CreateObject("MyCOMObject")
```

The component pulls some data from a database and hands string values which are assigned to Word DocumentVariables.

```
Set someClass = myCOMObject.GetSomeClass(123)
ActiveDocument.Variables("docaddress") = someClass.GetSenderAddress(456)
```

All string values returned from the component are encoded in UTF-16 (codepage 1200).

**What happens**

The problem arises when the CRM system calls Word to create a new doc by DDE (winword.exe /n /dde): The string values from the component are turned into UTF-8 encoded strings.

All the static text inside the template stays nicely encoded in UTF-16 - example the **umlaut ü** inside my DocumentVariables is turned into **c3 b0** while it stays **fc** for the rest of the document (checked file in hex editor).

If I'm creating a document from a template with the same macro functionallity directly (without DDE) all strings are fine; i.e. are encoded in UTF-16.

**Side effects**
If I create a new document from my template, keep this document open and create a new document controlled by DDE the characters are encoded correctly!

This also works the other way round: creating a DDE controlled document first breaks the character encoding when creating a second document directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the solution is to replace the database access via **System.Data.OleDb**

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

OleDbParameter companyIdParam = command.CreateParameter();
companyIdParam.ParameterName = "companyId";
companyIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
companyIdParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
companyIdParam.Value = companyId;
command.Parameters.Add(companyIdParam);
```

by **System.Data.OracleClient**

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection);

OracleParameter companyIdParam = command.CreateParameter();
companyIdParam.ParameterName = "I_COMPANYID";
companyIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
companyIdParam.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
companyIdParam.Value = companyId;
command.Parameters.Add(companyIdParam);
```

Or by **Oracle.DataAccess.Client**

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection);

OracleParameter companyIdParam = command.CreateParameter();
companyIdParam.ParameterName = "companyId";
companyIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
companyIdParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
companyIdParam.Value = companyId;
command.Parameters.Add(companyIdParam);
```